# cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale get error: Insufficient memory in OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, opencv, cascade-classifier

Hello everyone I have the following code:

```java
public boolean isContainsFace(String path){
        Mat matImage = Imgcodecs.imread(path);

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(matImage, faceDetections);

        return !faceDetections.empty();
    }
```

I use it to check if there are faces in the photos. And that's when I tried a larger-than-usual photo, I got the following error:

```java
E/cv::error(): OpenCV(4.6.0-dev) Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 1281229312 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file E:/OpenCV/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 73
E/org.opencv.objdetect: objdetect::detectMultiScale_15() caught cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.6.0-dev) E:/OpenCV/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 1281229312 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.findyourselfinthephoto, PID: 25403
    CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.6.0-dev) E:/OpenCV/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 1281229312 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
    ]
        at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale_5(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(CascadeClassifier.java:195)
        at com.example.findyourselfinthephoto.Helpers.PhotoHelper.isContainsFace(PhotoHelper.java:41)
        at com.example.findyourselfinthephoto.Fragments.Home.onRequestHandlePathOz(Home.java:164)
        at br.com.onimur.handlepathoz.utils.HandlePathOzUtils$getRealPath$1.invokeSuspend(HandlePathOzUtils.kt:107)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterResume(Scopes.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:102)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@e6b34af, Dispatchers.Main]
```

What should i do to fix that?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale-get-error-insufficient-memory-in-outofmemoryerror/11293

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the amount of memory set android:largeHeap attribute in the  in AndroidManifest.xml file to true